# How to fix ubuntu load screen after install nvidia driver (331,38)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, proprietary

I installed nvidia proprietary driver (331.38 on ubuntu 14.04 by sudo apt-get install nvidia-331) and now the Ubuntu load screen is with a bad resolution (640x480). I followed some recommendations from previous questions but I can not increase the resolution. I would like to return to 1920x1080 resolution.

Comment: just remove `xorg.conf` file by running `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: this file do not exists in ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: try `nvidia-current` instead of `nvidia-331`

Comment: Haven't seen this anywhere else, so I'm not sure if it always works. But switching from DVI - VGA --> Display to HDMI --> Display fixed this problem for me.

Comment: I had to add a line `Option "UseEDID" "false"` to the `Section "Screen"`. This prevented the NVIDIA driver to query the supported modes and still somehow decide that the optimal resolution for the display is not optimal at all. Hope it helps you and others

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem a few days ago, removing the xorg.conf created by Nvidia seems to fix the problem. Execute the commands below after pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 on GDM screen or within GNOME.

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
sudo touch /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Comment: lifesaver. I actually found `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe` and copied that over to xorg.conf

Answer (score 0):

I installed the `nvidia-396` driver through the .deb file for CUDA Toolkit 9.2, downloaded from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). Running Ubuntu 18.04.

I somehow ended up with a complete blank `xorg.conf` and was also stuck at 640x480 resolution.

I solved by running `sudo nvidia-xconfig`. This generated a populated `xorg.conf` which overrode the blank one. Resolution was fixed after a reboot.

Answer (score -1):

When I did that on my xps 15 (optimus gt 540) the screen was blank,
So I removed the drivers (sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*) and 
then reinstalled ubuntu-desktop, then the resolution was fine.

Comment: I need the nvidia drivers to use Steam and another things. The resolution problem occurs only in the load screen (Ubuntu .... screen), after load the resolution of all becomes normal (but the load screen is ugly).

Comment: This is not a solution to fix the actual problem

Comment: I suppose by some pedantic definition it could be, but I would say that is probably being far too literal - and that, in a situation like this, we should assume that, unless the OP said they were willing to uninstall the drivers, they want to fix the problem *and* keep the drivers.